# Get data from parent form in a popup CRM Dynamics 2015

Tags: javascript, iframe, microsoft-dynamics

I have a button on an entity form which opens a CRM modal. I need to get to form data from the IFrame inside that modal, I tried a lot of ways. I included ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx reference in the IFrame html, I also tried with

```
$.each(parent.window.frames, function (i, val) {
               if (parent.window.frames[i].Xrm.Page.data.entity != null) {
});

window.parent.Xrm.Page ...
window.top.opener.frames[0].Xrm.Page... //here window top opener is null

window.parent.opener.crmForm.all.name.DataValue //window parent opener is null
```

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how your modal is created?  Is this a jQuery-UI style modal that inserts a frame in the page or something like window.showModalDialog (deprecated!)?

Assuming a dialog somewhere in the same 'top' frame, this is how I handle this.  Let's say I have a form script on the Account record.  In my onload function I configured ISV_Account_Form_onload:

```
// Return some data from the form
function ISV_GetAccountData(){ 
  return { 
    Name: Xrm.Page.getAttribute('name').getValue()
  };
}

// Runs onload
function ISV_Account_Form_onload{
  // Define my function on the top window
  top.ISV_GetAccountData = ISV_GetAccountData;
}
```

Then in my inline-frame I would call:

```
var accountData = top.ISV_GetAccountData();
```

This can also work from a pop-up window:

```
var accountData = top.opener.top.ISV_GetAccountData();
```

For brevity I've excluded cleaning up the function when the form unloads, making sure the function is defined before calling, etc.